# Update statement, update value is conditionally evaluated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below pseudo code written that I want to implement in T-SQL. I need this code included in an existing stored procedure, I was trying to achieve the below with function call passing in a temp table as a parameter, is it possible to pass a temp table as a function parameter. Please let me know if there is a better approach to this.

Table: `#Temp_Table` has a column `RefId` which refers to `#TempReadUpdateValue.Id`. There are rules to identify if the `#TempReadUpdateValue.Id` can be applied to `#Temp_Table.RefId`.

- Rule 1: the data qualifies in the DateRange
- Rule 2: the `#TempReadUpdateValue.Id` is available if `(Allowed - Used) > 0`.
  Allowed is fixed value and used will increment as its assigned.

I want to achieve the above with an `UPDATE` statement on `Temp_Table`, the challenge that I face is `#Temp_Table.RefId = #TempReadUpdateValue.Id`, need to increment

```
#TempReadUpdateValue.Used = #TempReadUpdateValue.Used + #Temp_Table.Units
```

every next row in `#Temp_Table` need to re-evaluate rules #1 and #2 for `RefId` assignment.

Update statement:

```sql
DECLARE @OLD INT = 0; -- THIS CAN ALSO BE SET TO 1, basically passed in as param to the stored procedure.

CREATE TABLE #TempReadUpdateValue
(
    Id INT,
    From_Date DateTime,
    Thru_Date DateTime,
    Allowed int,
    Used int
)

CREATE TABLE #Temp_Table 
(
    Pk_ID INT,
    DOS DateTime,
    Units Int,
    Ref_Id int
)

UPDATE #Temp_Table 
SET Ref_Id = CASE 
                WHEN @OLD = 0 THEN 121
                ELSE NewImplementation(DOS, Units, #TempReadUpdateValue)
             END

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION NewImplementation
    (@DOS DATETIME, @Units INT, #TempReadUpdateValue)
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Id INT
    DECLARE @Allowed INT
    DECLARE @Used INT

    SELECT 
        @Id = Id, 
        @Allowed = Allowed, 
        @Used = Used 
    FROM 
        #TempReadUpdateValue
    
    DECLARE @ReturnValue INT = 0

    IF (@Id > 0) AND  (@Allowed - @Used ) > 0
    BEGIN
        @ReturnValue = @Id;

        UPDATE #TempReadUpdateValue 
        SET Used = (Used + @Units);
    END 

    RETURN @ReturnValue 
END
```

Comment: This *isn't* T-SQL. What ever language you are using, it's not what you have tagged. `==` isn't a valid operator in T-SQL and neither are things like the braces or that IIF logic using `?` and `:`. I have no idea what language is is meant to be. I suggest finding out what language/RDBMS you are really using and retagging appropriately.

Comment: @TechieNerd You need to paste your (simplified) C# code (as you refer to some loops) or remove that code if it is purely SQL question. As of now the question is written in unanswerable manner.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you would describe *what* you are trying to achieve rather than providing pseudo-SQL. This way, people (including myself) can understand your question better and hopefully be able to help you out. For example, provide a brief outline of the "workflow" you're aiming to achieve, the relevant tables involved and their schema, and perhaps a small amount of example data.

Comment: It is completely unclear. This is when C# and SQL have fallen into a meat grinder. Also it looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): please describe what is the source of updatable IDs and what should be done with them, not how. SQL is not about loops, it works on sets of data.